# change the path where cronjob writes to

Tags: node.js, shell, unix, cron

I have a node js script which writes to a file in the same location where the nodejs script is.
I created a shell script to call this nodejs script (and some other commands which takes the output file from nodejs as input)
I schedule this shell script as a cron job. Now the output from nodejs gets saved in my /home folder. How do I change this so the file is in script folder?

I can't change this nodejs script since its from another team.

Answer (score 0):

I think running you shell script that calls the nodejs script from inside the script folder is might work.

Either that or the nodejs script writes to "/filename" instead of "./filename" which i think you can only fix by changing the nodejs script, maybe ask the team that made it.

Comment: my shell script and my node js script both are in same directory. The nodejs script has only ```var fileName = "EXPORT_" + dateFormat + ".json";
        var filePath = fileName;      ```                                                                                        And then                                                                                                               ```fs.appendFile(filePath, fileData, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        }); ```

Comment: i think modifying fileName = "EXPORT_" + dateFormat + ".json"; to fileName = "./EXPORT_" + dateFormat + ".json"; might do the trick

Comment: Thanks ..actually i don't want to change the nodejs script since this script is from another team and from time to time this may be changed (by that team).  is there no other way ?

Answer (score 0):

so i found a way, in crontab i did cd  and then script name.

`0 0 * * * cd <path to scripts> && ./<script> >> <path/log.out> 2>&1`